# Wildfly 8 Basic Authentication

Tags: authentication, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly

I got a Java-Webapp running on Wildfly 8. I try to secure my restful webservice with resteasy Annotations. I use the command line tool curl to test the rest api.

The basic authentication setup seems to work. Http requests to Webservices with annotation "@PermitAll" work fine. Curl says:

```
~ % curl -v http://localhost:8080/ItilityServer-web/rest/account 
> GET /ItilityServer-web/rest/account HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.40.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
< Server: WildFly/8
< Content-Length: 0
< Date: Wed, 28 Jan 2015 10:47:11 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

But http requests containing valid username and password get rejected with status code 401 not authorized. Wildfly logs the error unmatched password:

```
2015-01-28 11:42:43,565 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX000263: Executing query SELECT a.password FROM Account a WHERE a.name = ? with username hans
2015-01-28 11:42:43,566 DEBUG [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX000283: Bad password for username hans
```

But this is not true. The decrypted authorization details "aGFuczpoZWxtaWhlbG1paGVsbWk=" are hans:helmihelmihelmi and this username and password are stored in my db. The same jpql-queries as the security-domain uses result in an unsername "hans" and his password "helmihelmihelmi".

Here my setup:

web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.role.based.security</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Application</realm-name>
</login-config>

<security-role>
    <role-name>store</role-name>
</security-role>

</web-app>
```

(I don't know what security realms are, so I just left this property in the login-config tag)

My security domain in standalone.xml

```
<security-domain name="DBLogin" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT a.password FROM Account a WHERE a.name = ?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT a.userRole FROM Account a WHERE a.name = ?"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="Base64"/>
            <module-option name="hashCharset" value="UTF-8"/>
            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

Restful webservice

```
@GET
@RolesAllowed(AuthRole.STORE)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getAccountByName() {
    Response.ResponseBuilder builder = Response.ok();
    return builder.build();
}
```

and import.xml to create user on startup

```
insert into Account(id, name, email, password, user_role) values (0, 'hans', 'john.smith@mailinator.com', 'helmihelmihelmi', 'store') 
insert into Store(id, name, zipcode, street, housenumber, town, account_id) values(0, 'Edeka', 72622, 'stephanstraße', 10, 'Reudern', 0);
```

Don't know how to find a solution, because I don't even know the problem. Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mustn't store the unencrypted password in the database. WildFly expects you to store the **hashed** password, using the hash algorithm and encoding specified in the `login-module` configuration.

When creating a new `Account`, use

```
org.jboss.security.auth.spi.Util.createPasswordHash()
```

to obtain the hashed password to store.

As a rule, storing raw passwords is a security risk.

Comment: That was the solution! Thanks a lot.

Comment: IMHO storing a raw or insecurely hashed password should be considered criminal negligence these days.